# how to prevent SQL Injection in a asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-injection

For email entry in a text box by the user i am doing client side check, to find whether the email is valid or not

```
 string emailexist = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) as count FROM tbl_user WHERE Email=@Email ";     


   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" ValidationGroup="Login" ControlToValidate="txtUserName"
                            ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" CssClass="Error"
                             runat="server" />
```

is this regular expression good enough to prevent sql injection for email.

Other Text:

```
   string groupExistQuery = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT GroupID) as count FROM tbl_group WHERE GroupName=@GroupName";
```

I am doing a query in server side to check whether the group name entered by the user is already available in the database, there is a strong possibility to perform sql injection here. How should I prevent from it.

Comment: I thought we'd been over this: don't use the `asp` tag.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - I really wish the discussion on meta had resulted in `asp` being changed to `asp-classic` :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A regex is **unrelated** to SQL injection (blacklisting etc is never the strongest approach); however, the use of the parameter `@Email` means (assuming it *remains* parameterised) that is **not** susceptible to SQL injection.

SQL injection relates to inappropriate concatenation of input; the main tool to fight it is parameters, which has already happened here.

For example, if you did:

```
var sql = "SELECT ...snip... WHERE Email='" + email + "'"; // BAD!!!!!
```

then **that** is heavily susceptible to SQL injection. By using a parameter, the value is not treated as part of the query, so the attacker does not have at attack vector.

Comment: This is true across most (if not all) languages and DBMS systems. Parameterised queries are almost always the best solution. I can't count the number of times I've seen someone use custom validation code and then have a look of horrified surprise when someone hits them with a `DROP TABLES`.

Answer (score 6):

If you use parameterised values, you are going to be fine regardless, you can not inject via parameters, only via concatenated values.

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent it by not using Direct SQL and using parameterised queries and/or Stored Procedures instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use parameterised values
2. Encode your strings

Comment: with a heavy, heavy emphasis on 1; option 2 is something most folks **will** get wrong. Personally, I'd limit any use of 2 to explicitly white-listed values (rather than black-listed)

Comment: @MarcGravell - Agreed. Conversion to appropriate types does alert you to a formatting issue, but it's certainly not a security measure.

Comment: Html encoding does prevent some attacks

Comment: @user182630 HTML encoding stops XSS attacks, not SQL attacks. If you are HTML-encoding for data-access, them you are doing it.... Er, wrong!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) is the reply from Microsoft Pattern & Practices group to your question.

In general, the simple rule is: not to use dynamic SQL generation and if you do, sanitize your input.

Never just concatenate strings for building your SQL query. If you need to build a query on your own in your application, then  use parametrized SQL queries with parameters -- this way you are on a safe side.

Here is an example from the document I provide the link to above:

```
  DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
  SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter( 
             "LoginStoredProcedure", connection);
  myCommand.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@au_id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11);
  myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters["@au_id"].Value = SSN.Text;

  myCommand.Fill(userDataset);
```

Comment: My comment was addressed.  Carry on :)

Comment: Using type-safe parameters is just a way to sanitize your input, in my opinion.

Comment: See my comment on Mark's answer. Custom filtering cannot possibly take into account every possible SQL injection avenue, including all syntaxes, encodings and trickery that attackers will come up with. I have seen people try this, and some have been very smart with their filtering, but every time I have seen it end in catastrophe when their system is comprimised. Parameterised queries are an absolute solution because they treat the values as data in a totally separated context and cannot ever be parsed as code.

Comment: Why do you mean that "sanitizing" means "filtering the input"? Did you read my answer and the sample code?